# Better way to do this with Node.js, Express, and MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, linux, express

So I was wondering if anyone had a better method for my problem. Basically I want a record inside a record that I'm inserting into a database.  What I mean is, I need to have a history of all the changes made to the record when updated. So whenever the record is updated, I save the info in a "Updates" column.  Every time theres an update, I select the updates from that record, concatenate the new info onto the old updates and inserting it.  See my code below.

```
app.post("/updateRecord", function(req,res){
  var prevResultUpdates = "";
  async function first(){
    con.query("SELECT * FROM Equipment WHERE Serial="+req.body.serial+" AND Part="+req.body.part, function(err,result,fields){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result[0]['Updates'])
      return prevResultUpdates= prevResultUpdates + "," + result[0]['Updates']

    });
  }
  async function second(){
    await first();
    var customer = req.body.customer;
    var update = "\'" + prevResultUpdates + ',' + req.body.update + "," + Number(Date.now()) + "," + req.body.customer + ',' +"\'";
    var serial = req.body.serial;
    var part = req.body.part;
    var sql="Update `Equipment` SET `Customer`= '"+customer+"', `Updates`="+update+" WHERE Serial=" + serial + " AND Part=" + part;
    con.query(sql,function(err,result,fields){
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(result)
    })
  }
  second();

  res.end()

})
```

Any thoughts on how to do this better?

Comment: how about using models ?

Comment: @Eitank With MySQL? I thought that was just with mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bunch of suggestions here.

First, put a column in your table like this:

```
last_change TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

It will always contain the time of the most recent INSERT or UPDATE operation on each row, automatically without you needing to mention it in your SQL.

Second, be aware that

```
UPDATE Equipment SET Updates = Updates + ' some text string'
```

works. You can change a column in place, without fetching its former value. But, this can fail when the column gets too long. So, do this instead.

```
UPDATE Equipment SET Updates = RIGHT(Updates + ' some text string', 255)
```

assuming your Updates column is defined as `VARCHAR(255)`. I used `RIGHT()` rather than `LEFT()` because presumably the most recent update is the most interesting.

Third, you'd probably be wise to normalize this, to add an `Equipment_history` table. Instead of appending your update log to a column, insert a new row into `Equipment_history`.  That table might have these columns

```
equipment_history_id  INT          primary key
equipment_id          INT          foreign key to Equipment table
customer              VARCHAR(255) identity of the customer 
update                VARCHAR(255) reason for update
last_change           TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This lets you reconstruct the history of your updates if need be.